# VBA to not delete file if the file name contains certain text?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a file with code that saves the file with a certain file name and deletes the old file. However, I don't want it to delete the old file if the old file was named =JE Template. I have the below code but can't get it to work. Someone please help me get this one across the finish line.

```
Sub Save()

Dim File_Name
Dim Old_File As String
Dim JE_Template As String

File_Name = Range("File_Name")
Old_File = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
JE_Template = "=JE Template"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & File_Name & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

If Not Old_File.Contains("JE Template") Then
Kill Old_File
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: `If InStr(Old_File, "JE Template") = 0 Then`

Comment: So it's not deleting the =JE Template file but it's not deleting the file if it doesn't contain JE Template either.

Comment: To debug, perhaps add some `Debug.Print` statements to see if it's entering the `If` block? But `InStr(...) = 0` is either `True` or `False`. It can't be both. I don't know why the `Kill` statement is failing, but if it is, that's a different issue.

Comment: Will Debug.Print work if it isn't debugging though?

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/print-method).

Comment: So I put the below code in to see if the InStr was working but it is returning no regardless of whether the old file is named =JE Template or not.

Comment: If InStr(Old_File, "=JE Template") = 0 Then
    Range("C5").Formula2R1C1 = "Yes"
    Else
    Range("C5").Formula2R1C1 = "No"
    'Kill Old_File
    End If

Comment: Learn to use `Debug.Print`: `Debug.Print Old_File, InStr(Old_File, "=JE Template") = 0` and inspect the output in the Immediate Window.